# Neo4j import on Docker

Tags: docker, neo4j, docker-compose

I am trying to use the Neo4j-import tool to bulk import csv files into a new neo4j database. I can successfully perform this but for the dockerized neo4j to recognize it, I need to restart the docker. Is there any way to do this without having to restart the container? I have tried using the cypher csv import but that for some reason doesn't support the large dataset ~76k relationships

Comment: If you cannot stop the container, why using containers ? Also 76k is very small, LOAD CSV can load millions of rows.

Comment: For me that was too slow at first but I exported to csv instead of querying the sql database and it worked very snappy. Thank you